# Single word for 'being one step ahead of others'

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for synonyms as single words having the meaning of 'being one step ahead of others'.

Comment: **lead·ing** *adj.* **1.** Having a position in the lead; foremost: the leading candidate. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/leading

Comment: The "game" of "being one step ahead of others" is called one-upmanship. You buy a Cadillac, so I buy a Mercedes; you buy a Bentley, so I buy a Mazzeratti (the one priced at a million dollars!), etc.

Comment: It's not clear what meaning you are looking for. Literally one step ahead, as in walking/running? One step ahead in a process? Or simply being more advanced in a quantitative way?

Answer (score 3):

"Innovator" (or "innovative"), "pioneering", "scout", "trailblazer", "vanguard", or "visionary", depending upon usage.

Answer (score 3):

***Pacesetter*** is a common term for someone who is in the position you describe.

pace·set·ter noun \ˈpās-ˌse-tər\
: a person who runs ahead of the other runners in a race in order to set a pace

as in, a company that has been a ***pacesetter*** in its field for offering health care benefits to employees

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pacesetter

Answer (score 1):

One such description is *frontrunner* — or *frontrunning*, if you prefer the adjectival form.

Comment: Per http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/364 for the use–mention distinction, please use an italic face not a bold one. It makes the page look
 too heavy otherwise, and furthermore runs counter to typographic convention both on this site and in scholarly works.

Comment: @tchrist sorry but I smiled :) (*not in a bad way!*)

Answer (score 1):

You could say **be a [notch](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/notch) above the others** and *be **superior** (to others*).

> [*notch above*](http://ofen.wiktionary.org/wiki/a_notch_above) (someone or something) and *a notch better* (than someone or something): a little higher in quality than someone or something
>
> superior: of high or higher quality; great or greater in amount, number, or degree; better than other people

be one step ahead : to be slightly better prepared or more successful than someone else (usually + of) [**Source**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+one+step+ahead)

Comment: similar, a *cut above*.

Answer (score 0):

[Advanced](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Advanced) suggests the meaning you are looking for:

> being at a higher level than others.

I also suggest the useful expression: *[to be a cut above something or somebody](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+a+cut+above)*:

> to be better than other things or people: he is so smart that he is always a cut above all his friends.  Our new luxury apartments are a cut above the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider the phrase *[early adopter](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/early_adopter)*, which means:

> A person who begins using a product or service at or around the time it becomes available.

The phrase *early adopter* sometimes is used to describe people who are *[ahead of the curve](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ahead_of_the_curve)*. *Ahead of the curve* is an idiom for “Changing before competitors” or “in the forefront of change”.

Another related phrase is “on the *[bleeding edge](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bleeding_edge#Noun)*”, which means using “Something very current or modern, where there may actually be a hazard or risk in using it”.

Answer (score 0):

Greed. People who have to be ahead of others have an inadequate personal self concept and are not content just being themselves--so they greddily seek more attention from others

Comment: This is reading way too much into the situation compared to what the question is actually asking....

Answer (score 0):

**Prescient** is what came to my mind immediately.

From [oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prescient):

> Having or showing knowledge of events before they take place:
>   a prescient warning

Comment: Hi Tapioca, that's a great word!  Can you provide a dictionary definition for that to assist the OP and other users of this site?

Answer (score 0):

I think the word ***[perspicacious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perspicacious)*** is a good fit.

: of acute mental vision or discernment : KEEN

*As some of the nation’s most perspicacious observers have noted, self-regulation is a crucial component of fixing what’s wrong with social media.
—Gilad Edelman, Wired, 30 Sep. 2021*

Other words that might highlight the sense of relative farsightedness (including the word [farsighted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/farsighted) itself) are:

***[Sagacious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sagacious)***

: of keen and farsighted penetration and judgment

*… the winner is praised for his sagacious grasp of the hopes and anxieties of the public, the loser is excoriated for the many and obvious blunders that derailed his candidacy …
—Hendrik Hertzberg, New Yorker, 18 Dec. 2000*

I think the example sentence above wonderfully encapsulates the idea of being a step ahead of one’s competitors, too.

***Farsighted***

: having or showing foresight or good judgment : SAGACIOUS
*a farsighted leader*