# What's another way of saying "one step ahead"?

Tags: phrases, idioms

I'm looking for another way of saying "one step ahead". This phrase or idiom should be mainly used for describing someone that can think earlier than others, and can prepare in advance as well.

Comment: See also [Single word for 'being one step ahead of others'](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/175575/191178)

Answer (score 0):

A similar phrase is

> **ahead of the game**

[Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ahead+of+the+game) says

> Gaining or maintaining an advantage in a situation, often by completing a task before its given deadline.
>
> If you are ahead of the game, you know about and are using all the most recent developments in a particular area, especially compared to other people or organizations you are competing with.

---

Another related expression is

> **think on one's feet**

[Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/think+on+(one%27s)+feet) says

> To be able to think clearly in times of stress, especially when forming a solution to a pressing problem.
>
> If you think on your feet, you make good decisions quickly and react quickly when things change.

Answer (score 0):

> The ideal candidate should demonstrate/possess **foresight.**

**foresight** (n.)

> The ability to predict or the action of **predicting what will
> happen or be needed** in the future. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/foresight)

---

> **Foresight**: anticipate, predict and prepare for your future. [*Elgar Introduction to Theories of Organization*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Elgar_Introduction_to_Theories_of_Organi/JqV-DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=foresight%20%20predict%20and%20prepare&pg=PT85&printsec=frontcover) (2018)

> *Strategic leaders* need **foresight** to identify future trends. **Foresight** is the ability to see what is coming next. It is not so much a trait as a skill that can be developed by careful research,
> personal reflection, and interactive discussion about the signs of the
> times. [D. Ebner and F. Smith; *Strategi Planning*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Strategic_Planning/LmxhCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=foresight%20will%20happen%20plan&pg=PT28&printsec=frontcover) (2015)